# Discuss the continuity and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Discuss the continuity and differentiability of $f$ at zero, where
>   $$f(x) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             x^2 & \quad  \text{if} \space x \gt 0 \\
>             0 & \quad \text{if}\space x \leq 0.
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
>  $$

I am stuck here trying to figure out the approach to discussing this.

Any suggestions or pushes in the right direction are greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you stuck on continuity at $0?$ Do you know the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a function is continuous if $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = f(c)$$ This function is therefore continuous at $x = 0$ as $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x) = 0$$ However continuity does not imply differentiability (only differentiability implies continuity), so we need to examine differentiability separately.

Note the definition of differentiability,

$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} = f'(c) $$

For x = 0 we need to have

$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} = f'(c) $$

for the function to be differentiable at 0.

We can check this by taking the derivative of both pieces of the function at x = 0 and checking if they are equivalent at that point:

$$f'(x)=\begin {cases}2x \qquad if \; x>0\\0 \qquad if \; x\le 0\end{cases}$$

Hence both derivatives are equal at x = 0 so by the definition of differentiability we can say that the function is not only continuous at x = 0 but it is also differentiable at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You have:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=f(0)=0
$$
so the function is continuous.

For the derivative you can find the same result since

$$
f'(x)=
\begin {cases}
2x \qquad if \; x>0\\
0 \qquad if \; x\le 0
\end{cases}
$$

so the function is derivable in $x=0$.

Note that for the second derivative the result is different.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
To show continuity you can count $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-}f(x)$. If these two limits equal, than the function is continuos.

You also know $f'(x)$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ and $x \in (-\infty,0)$. So again count limits from both sides.